# Is it possibile to use react-dates on a stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, gatsby, react-dates

I'm setting a contact form with Gatsbyjs and need a datepicker. Is it possible to use react-dates on a stateless component? I tried but without success (since [the instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates) refers to a class component I don't really know how to behave here).

This is an example of my form without react-dates (I'm using Formik):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik'

function encode(data) {
    return Object.keys(data)
        .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
        .join("&");
}

const ContactForm = () => (
    <>
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ email: '', name: '', start: '', end: '', message: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                fetch("/", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                    body: encode({
                        "form-name": "contact",
                        ...values
                    })
                })
                .then(() => alert("Thanks!"))
                .catch(error => alert(error))
            }}
        >
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                <Form name="contact" data-netlify="true" action="/grazie">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
                        <label>
                            <Field type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name and Surname" />
                            <ErrorMessage name="name" component="div" />
                        </label>
                    <br />
                        <label>
                            <Field type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
                            <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" />
                        </label>
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Send</button>
                </Form>
                )}
        </Formik>
</>
)

export default ContactForm
```

Now since it's an stateless component I can't add {this.etc.etc} so I don't know how to config react-dates. This is the code I should add:

```
<DateRangePicker
  startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
  startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
  endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
  onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55454138/2232626

I just created a component with the date-picker component and then imported it where the main Formik page resides. 
Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/723l233my1

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject 'this' as a prop like so:

```
 const ContactForm = (props) => ( ...
      // props.that ....
 )

 // call it where you need it
 <ContactForm  
     that = {this}  
     ... 
 > 
    ...
 </ContactForm>
```

Comment: just solved in another way (just added a new answer), thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `this` then it's not a good use case to make functional components, why not make class components here. It will be really easy

Comment: I know this seems the most reasonable choice, but I needed to do like that because I was trying to make it work with Formik (under Gatsby), and Formik doesn't require a class function. Anyway I get it working (just added a new answer).